# com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData; vs java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

I am using tomcat7, java 1.6 to access a mysql db with `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. I was going to get metaData from a table like

```
java.sql.ResultSet set=getStuff();
ResultSetMetaData meta = set.getMetaData();
```

The problem is , set.getMetaData returns `java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;` but I am using mysql with jdbc, so shouldn't it be returning `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;`? Did I import something wrong? If not when will `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;` be used or whats the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role of the driver is actually to abstract the use of database specific code. 
So you just specify the driver and then interact with an api that is not database dependent.

If you have a closer look you will see that `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData` is an implementation of the interface `java.sql.ResultSetMetaData`.

And for sake of decoupling you are better off working with the interface (so you are not tied to a specific database in your code)